# Posgres: Order by ::timestamp asc and desc of jsonb column giving same results, how to order by last timestamp

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4

I have this query which retrieves 1 row based on UUID doc_id of table documents, which also has a field column type jsonb:

```
select 
    DISTINCT ON (doc_id) 
    *
    FROM ( 
        select d.doc_id, c.comments 
        from documents as d 
        cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(comments) 
        WITH ORDINALITY c(comments)
        WHERE (c.comments ->> 'isUser'):: boolean is false 
        order by (c.comments ->>'timestamp')::timestamp desc
    ) as s;
```

When I try:

```
        order by (c.comments ->>'timestamp')::timestamp desc
```

I get exact same result. I even tried with `timestamptz`:

```
        order by (c.comments ->>'timestamp')::timestamptz asc
```

Sample content of jsonb comments column:

```
[...
{
    "text": "30",
    "timestamp": "2018-11-11T09:13:23.242Z", // older
    "isUser": false
},{
    "text": "31",
    "timestamp": "2018-11-11T12:53:48.620Z", // LATEST
    "isUser": false
}]
```

as you can see object with text 30 is older, yet it always gets returned in the queries above.

Comment: In your previous question, you hadn't initially mentioned about  using  the timestamp, so I added `WITH ORDINALITY`. You may omit it. I had used `ORDER BY` outside the subquery in my answer, which it seems ,you've changed while copying the answer. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ada278ab3748d95f74065b3281d9ac5e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is irrelevant to the final outcome because it only applies to the SELECT statement within which it's used, i.e. your subquery. You then perform another query on those results, using `DISTINCT ON` which will do whatever calculations and return you the results in *some* order but probably not the one you want.

To allow you to order in the outer query, the fields you want to use in the order must be accessible at that level. That means the subquery will have to also return the timestamp field, then the outer query can order on that but not select it (to keep the returned columns the same).

```
select 
    DISTINCT ON (doc_id) 
    doc_id, comments
    FROM ( 
        select d.doc_id, c.comments, (c.comments ->>'timestamp')::timestamp AS comment_timestamp
        from documents as d 
        cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(comments) 
        WITH ORDINALITY c(comments)
        WHERE (c.comments ->> 'isUser'):: boolean is false 
    ) as s
ORDER BY doc_id, comment_timestamp DESC
```

I may be missing something but it seems to be you don't need the subquery anyway, wouldn't this work?

```
select DISTINCT ON (d.doc_id) d.doc_id, c.comments 
from documents as d 
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(comments) 
WITH ORDINALITY c(comments)
WHERE (c.comments ->> 'isUser'):: boolean is false 
order by d.doc_id, (c.comments ->>'timestamp')::timestamp desc
```

Comment: Damn IMPRESSIVE! very elegant the final solution, thanks so much It works perfectly.